# iOS application will not install, continually displays "waiting"

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, itunes-store

Having issues trying to install an application on an iOS device. The device is an iPhone 5 with iOS 6 so no environment issues.

Have tried to install the application via TestFlight, and via iTunes with the .ipa file. Tried restarting the device with no further success.

Device gives no warnings, errors, the application just sits with a label showing "waiting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, the device had no free space remaining. Unfortunately the iOS doesn't make this obvious and only discovered it by accident when I was performing a remote desktop connection on the user's Macbook and had iTunes open.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload ipa again on testflight and download it may be this time gets work. Also there can be a reason of network connection check it.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > General > Usage > Delete app